# Python, BeautifulSoup - print only links which contains <img> in content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to set up in beautifulSoup that I can print only links that has `<img>` inside its content?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
import urllib
import re
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urlparse

url = "http://www.nytimes.com"

htmlcontent = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent)
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print link.contents
```

which print outs all content inside links. But my true need is to print links that has `<img>` tags inside it content and I don't know how to do that...

any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to find `img` tag inside the link:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if link.find('img'):
        print link
```